# SQL Server UDF Using C#

Tags: c#, sql, user-defined-functions

How can I create a  `User Defined Function` **UDF** In `SQL Server`, I was looking for an example, Could you provide a very simple example using `C#`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. SQL Server 2008 contains SQL CLR runtime that runs .NET languages.

Comment: So I can only use Visual Basic, C#?.
In other SQL version, like 2000, or 2005 Is it possible?

Comment: Do you need it? If it's a function, it might be called for lots of rows and lots of times, and this approach might be slow... And you might get memory leaks and crash SQL Server.  If you absolutely must call unmanaged code (C,C++) from inside SQL Server, call the code via P/Invoke from the C#/VB.NET assembly. See this thread for more info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlnetfx/thread/4a032c4b-1402-4c53-b34e-8c8bd724f904

Comment: I was planning to do an aggregate function, but for testing yield, i need to use a UDF.